# Which process creates the 'Desktop' folder?

Tags: filesystem, users

I don't use gnome nor kde desktops because my system isn't as fast as they require it to be, but even when I don't use them, a 'Desktop' folder is always in my home dir, I've delete it several times before but it's again there when I reboot the system, what do I need to do in order to delete it for ever?

Comment: I'm running i3 (i3.zekjur.net) and pcmanfm for files management, http://pastebin.com/1ATMHDVv this is the list of the processes I usually run, any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the package `xdg-user-dirs`.

From the package description:

```
xdg-user-dirs is a tool to help manage "well known" user directories
like the desktop folder and the music folder. It also handles
localization (i.e. translation) of the filenames.

The way it works is that xdg-user-dirs-update is run very early in the
login phase. This program reads a configuration file, and a set of
default directories. It then creates localized versions of these
directories in the users home directory and sets up a config file in
$(XDG_CONFIG_HOME)/user-dirs.dirs (XDG_CONFIG_HOME defaults to
~/.config) that applications can read to find these directories.
```

BTW: instead of removing it, you can of course also edit the `user-dirs.dirs` file and make it point to whatever directories you prefer...

Comment: Umm, I don't have the xdg-user-dirs package:

$ dpkg -l xdg-user-dirs
No packages found matching xdg-user-dirs.

How can I discover for myself which program is creating it?, is any other
package who could be doing it?

Comment: What windows manager do you use? (if any) or what other programs do you use? i pretty sure that nautilus will create a desktop folder if it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you will always have a "Desktop".  I could be wrong though.

Removing your "Desktop folder" would make it impossible to create stuff on the Desktop wouldn't it? And since it tries to always exist since it's basically like an always open folder wouldn't it just keep recreating itself? Also, what's the harm of having it?

Comment: I've deleted my desktop folder in natty, and the system uses my home dir when it needs the desktop folder.